# Firefox doesn't load external https javascript that fills out page content

Tags: javascript, firefox, https

I am in a situation where I am maintaining a page of opening hours that sometimes change. The page is used on several different platforms:

- An external CMS system on http Danish and English
- A Sharepoint intranet on https in Danish and English

In order to not have to change 4 different pages each time the opening hours change, I am loading the opening hours from a single javascript file which I have located on another server.

The script is here: https://blanketter.science.ku.dk/studenterservice/studenterservice-content.js

I am loading the page using the below code below:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://blanketter.science.ku.dk/studenterservice/studenterservice.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://blanketter.science.ku.dk/studenterservice/studenterservice-content.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="dynamic-intro">Error message if JavaScript disabled or Firefox used.</div>
        <div id="dynamic-specialOpeningHours">Error message if JavaScript disabled or Firefox used.</div>
        <div id="dynamic-contact">Error message if JavaScript disabled or Firefox used.</div>
        <div id="dynamic-closedWeeks">Error message if JavaScript disabled or Firefox used.</div>
        <div id="dynamic-directions">Error message if JavaScript disabled or Firefox used.</div>

        <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('content').className = "subpage wide";
</script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
writePageByLanguage('danish');
</script>
    </body>
</html>
```

You can see an example of this at http://www.science.ku.dk/uddannelser/studenterservice/vejledning_kopi/.

The site works as it should in **Chrome** and **Internet Explorer/Edge**, but **Firefox** fails to load the .js file and displays the eror message instead.

I have tried to place the .js file on a http:// server instead (different hosting provider). In this case Firefox is able to display the content.

Any help in clearing up how I could possible fix this while still having the .js file on my https server would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Firefox Network tab:

> blanketter.science.ku.dk uses an invalid security certificate.
>
> The certificate is not trusted because the issuer certificate is
>   unknown. The server might not be sending the appropriate intermediate
>   certificates. An additional root certificate may need to be imported.
>
> (Error code: sec_error_unknown_issuer)

You either need to get everyone visiting the site to manually trust the certificate, or get a new certificate that is signed by an authority that Firefox trusts, or fix the configuration of the server to provide the intermediate certificates.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will see if I can get our IT department to change this.